# Why am I not able to dynamically render my movies List off of a API get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out why I am not able to dynamically render my Movies component. I have a Movie Component that models each individual Movie. I then have a Movies component which maps every Movie from my api get request in index.jsx. It says, this.props.movies.map is not a function inside my Movies components. I quadrupled check that I was sending props the right way and it should be in the form of an array but nothing is working.

```
index.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Movies from './components/Movies.jsx'
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movieList: [],
    };
    
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=f3a857449b25e45a2c69af11e38fe7de')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ movieList: res.data })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header className="navbar"><h1>Bad Movies</h1></header> 
        
        <div className="main">
          <Movies 
          movies={this.state.movieList}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

Movie.jsx:
import React from 'react';

class Movie extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="movie">
                    <li className="movie_item">
                    <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.props.movie.poster_path}`} />
                    <div className="movie_description">
                        <h2>{this.props.movie.title}</h2>
                        <section className="movie_details">
                        <div className="movie_year">
                            <span className="title">Year</span>
                            <span>{this.props.movie.release_date.split('-')[0]}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="movie_rating">
                            <span className="title">Rating</span>
                            <span>{this.props.movie.vote_average}</span>
                        </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Movie;

Movies.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import Movie from './Movie.jsx'
class Movies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const mappedMovies = this.props.movies.map(movieObj => <Movie key={movieObj.id} movie={movieObj}/>); //This is where the error is pointing towards
    return (
      <div>
        {mappedMovies}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

Comment: hey ronny, not on my normal machine to help out and run your code however some things to try.
take a look your props in Movies.jsx, console log its type and make sure you are saving it as an array, if it is not an array reevalute how you call this.setState in app, you would hope your error would say Array.prototype.map is not a function if so.

Comment: So i changed this.setState({ movieList: res.data }) to this.setState({ movieList: [res.data] }) and that rendered it. So my api was in the form of an object and not an array?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Your API returns an `object` yet your state is set to an empty `array` as the initial value.

Then you populate your state `movieList` with the response from your API.

That means your `movieList` state actually becomes an `object` - therefor you get an error saying that

> movies is not a function

You *cannot* map an object.

---

Remember to tell your component to only pass `movieList` when it is populated with data like so:

```js
render () {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header className="navbar"><h1>Bad Movies</h1></header> 
        
        <div className="main">
          {this.state.movieList && <Movies 
          movies={this.state.movieList}
          /> }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error after making that change

Comment: Wait youre saying that in my movie component, change all of my this.props.movie to this.props.movies?

Comment: When i copy-paste your API in the browser it actually returns an object instead of an array. That means you cannot map an object. Mapping is only for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As Delice correctly said, there is a spelling mistake.
If you want this to be movie instead of movies, then change the below in index.js

```
 <div className="main">
      <Movies 
      movie={this.state.movieList}
  />
```

Comment: No, i deleted my comment. The props are correct. It just confused me with so many movie/movies names